# loaded the "xxxViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set

Tags: ios

My iOS application crashes with 'loaded "xxxViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set' error. Verified all things below.

1. Custom class is correctly set for nib file
2. All outlets and actions are set correctly for nib file
3. Controller class has below line set correctly

   self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

How to fix this issue?

Comment: You forgot the error.

Comment: If you select the view in IB and go to Connections tab under Referencing Outlets is "view" set to "File's Owner"?